# jQuery - Animate function

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a piece of code shown below:

```
$(".tagArea li").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).animate({
      borderWidth: "2px"
  }, 1000 );
});
$(".tagArea li").mouseout(function () {
$(this).animate({
      borderWidth: "1px"
  }, 1000 );
});
```

When I try to hover it on a particular list item, it properly animates but doesn't stop doing just once. It keeps doing 2 or 3 times.

How to avoid this, I 've tried many a times but no positive result occurs to me.

Kindly help.

Comment: can u provide [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating through jQuery, you could just use [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) and :hover.

```
.tagArea li {
  -webkit-transition: border-width .25s;
     -moz-transition: border-width .25s;
          transition: border-width .25s;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.tagArea li:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. That pretty much worked fine as I have expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(".tagArea li").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).animate({
      borderWidth: "2px"
  }, 1000 );
}) 
.mouseout(function () {
$(this).animate({
      borderWidth: "1px"
  }, 1000 );
});
```

detail reference has given in http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can use `.stop()` and you can chain your events:

```
$(".tagArea li").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({
      borderWidth: "+=5px"
   }, 500 );
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      borderWidth: "1px"
    }, 500 );
});
```

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YzaCZ/